# Knockout data-bind paste bug in Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, knockout.js, copy-paste

There appears to be a bug in VS 2012 with respect to data-bind attributes in .cshtml files and I'm wondering if anyone knows of a fix or workaround for this. I've verified that my co-workers experience the same issue, so I assume everyone does, but I can't find any reference to it (and I may just not be able to come up with a good enough set of search terms).

To reproduce the issue, take this text:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="value: myValue" />
```

and paste that into a cshtml file on an empty line twice. When you paste the second one, it adds 4 spaces to the data-bind and it looks like this:

```
<input type="text" data-bind="    value: myValue" />
```

It happens under various conditions (always seems to be pasting related). It's very frustrating to have to run around and then clean out all the spaces.

Does anyone know of a fix for this issue in VS2012 (VS2013 isn't a solution or us right now).

Comment: ctrl+k+d usually reformats the HTML. I am not aware of a setting that takes care of that automatically for pastes.

Comment: It's not a formatting issue, however. ctrl+k+d doesn't remove spaces from quoted text.

Comment: true that. There used to be a setting to set data-bind and how to format things. Can't find it anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only workable solution I've found so far is to disable Knockout support in intellisense (which I don't miss because I didn't realize it was there to begin with and all it does, as far as I can tell, is mess up my `data-bind` strings).

To disable it, I added the following `RegEdit` key:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\11.0\HTML Editor] 
"KnockoutSupportEnabled"="0"
```

I will not accept this answer, but post it here to inform others. I'll leave the answer unaccepted in the hope that someone will have a better solution at a later time.

I discovered this solution in an MSDN [blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/webdev/archive/2013/03/04/disabling-knockout-intellisense.aspx).

Comment: I tried setting this value to 0, but it gets set back to 1 each time i restart Visual studio (2015, with web essentials installed). It does disable knockout support as long as I don't restart VS however.